# Freemarker list-notation rendered as comment in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, apache, encoding, freemarker

I'm using Apache Freemarker as one of the code languages in a HTML editor where users can code a template. Let's say, a user writes this code for a list:

`<#list items as item>...</#list>`

This is the correct way to create a list in Freemarker. But, when I load the template at a later moment with functions such as `$("div").html(TEMPLATECODE)`, it will be rendered as:

`<#list items as item>...<!--#list-->`

How's this possible and how can I prevent html from transforming it to comments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A FreeMarker template is not HTML, but jQuery's `.html(string)` expects a string that's valid HTML. So if you pass a template to it, such weird things are bound to happen. Only passing in the *output* of the template makes sense. If you want to show the markup to the user instead, you should use `.text(string)`.